# How to split a dataframe column into 2 new columns, by slicing the all strings before the last item and last item

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a column which contains addresses. I would like to split the addresses so that the ending are in a column **Ending** and the strings before the the ending item are in a separate column **Beginning**. The address vary in length eg:

1. Main Street
2. Jon Smith Close
3. The Rovers Avenue

After searching different resources I came up with the following

```
new_address_df['begining'], new_address_df['ending'] = new_address_df['street'].str.split().str[:-1].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x))), new_address_df['street'].str.split().str[-1]
```

The code works but I am not sure if its the right way to write the code in python. Another option would have been to convert to list, modify the data in list form and then convert back to dataframe. I guess this might not be the best approach.

Is there a way to improve the above code if its not pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly alot of ways of doing this :) I would go for using str and rpartition. rpartition splits your string in 3 components, the remaining part, the partition string, and the part after remaining and the partition string. If you just take the first and remaining part you should be done.

```py
df[["begining", "ending"]]=df.street.str.rpartition(" ")[[0,2]]
```

Comment: Worked as expected. rpartition was the secret. I  knew my code was not pythonly elegant. Your code was simple to understand and would be easy to maintain. Would look up partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

You might use regular expression for this as follows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"street":["Main Street","Jon Smith Close","The Rovers Avenue"]})
df2 = df.street.str.extract(r"(?P<Beginning>.+)\s(?P<Ending>\S+)")
df = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
              street   Beginning  Ending
0        Main Street        Main  Street
1    Jon Smith Close   Jon Smith   Close
2  The Rovers Avenue  The Rovers  Avenue
```

Explanation: I used named capturing group which result in `pandas.DataFrame` with such named columns, which I then `concat` with original `df` with `axis=1`. In pattern I used group are sheared by single whitespace (`\s`), in group `Beginning` any character is allowed in group `Ending` only non-whitespace (`\S`) characters are allowed.

Comment: Would try out your method too